# Virtual Machine is slow if open from host OS but fast with Remote desktop connection

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have two virual machines on Host 2008 server.

If i operate the VM full screen from HOST OS then cursor moves slow but i use the remote desktop connection only to that machine then its normal.

what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vmware tools installed:

Right-click My Computer and select properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Performance settings and select "Adjust for best performance".

Et voila - Your console access is now lag-free :)

Edit: This is for the VIRTUAL computers, not the host. You didn't mention what OS they run, but I'm guessing Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fairly standard - with the console open, it's emulating a video card. With remote desktop, it's using an optimized protocol to send information back to the host (or remote) and passing that directly along to the local video drivers.

It's not quite the same thing, but think of the VM console as being more like a VNC connection than it is like actually sitting at a real hardware console.

Answer (score 0):

Are VMware tools installed?

Comment: yes , I have installed tools